# Azure search array field with unbounded items

Tags: .net, azure, elasticsearch

We have a property in our search document which consist of array of combination of country,categories and products.For many of the documents this combination gets close to 5k.When we retrieve the search documents because of this field having 5K items the search response body gets inflated and the response is slow from azure search. Is there a way to overcome this slow response.

This field is required to be retrieved cause we need it for further filtering and grouping.

Sample search will be to find documents which belong to Russia irrespective of the category and product or some cases find document belonging to category 8193C irrespective of countries and product. That is why we store it with the wild card to satisfy the partial filters. We could not store it as a complex object array because of the 3000 limit

Sample document .The field having the combination is  "combinationFilterItems" this can get close to 5K and we expect it to grow in future

```
{
      "@search.score": 1,
      "id": "df8ac070-f98d-4110-bae0-f86953d4a249",
      "combinationFilterItems": [
            "|RUS|8193C|P1603|",
            "|RUS|8193C|P1571|",
            "|RUS|8193C|P1568|",
            "|RUS|8193C|P1567|",
            "|RUS|8193C|*|"
            "|RUS|*|P1603|",
            "|RUS|*|*|"
            "|CAN|8193C|P1567|"

            .... max up to 5K combinations
      ]
}
```

We tried to search in parallel for each country or each category but search request gets throttled when we search in parallel for multiple countries or categories